# Loading images from facebook album limits the number of photos to only 25

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app that loads images from Facebook page album.
I build my app based on this tutorial:

[browsing Facebook albums from an android application](http://huguesjohnson.com/programming/java/android-fb-album/)

everything is right except that I am getting only 25 photos from my album although it has more than 380 photos.

I tried debugging the app and find why that is happening and noticed there is something like: limit=25 in the JSON link I get.

Aldo I tried to split the link and change the limit, but no luck :(
Btw, I want to get rid if the limit option.

Any hand for help, its much appreciated :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

**Using Graph API:**

**queries**

Get all albums ID: graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/albums
For each album ID, get the pictures: graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID?fields=photos.fields(source)

**consolidated query** - Provided the limit for the photos

graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/albums?fields=photos.limit(100).fields(source)

Comment: Please take a look at my try here:
http://graph.facebook.com/214891592041417?fields=photos.fields%28source%29

this number 214891592041417 is the Album_ID, it only returns 25 photos. If you look at the bottom of the JSON result page, you will see a link like this: 
http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/214891592041417/photos?pretty=1&fields=source&limit=25&after=Mjc4MzE3NTI1Njk4ODIz

It has a limit of 25, I need to get rid of this limit so I can load all of my album photos. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the API just returns a maximum of 25 photos, even if you set the limit higher. If yo want to get all photos, you need to use the "paging" object in the result and call the API again for the next 25 photos. You can do that in a recursive function, for example.

More information about the paging object: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1

(see "Traversing Paged Results")

Comment: cool, do you have a sample code based on my tutorial that loads the next set of images from my album? That would be great if you give a hand on it :)

Comment: unfortunately, i am not very good with android programming. but it should be really simple, just create a function to get /album-id/photos, parse the return value, get the paging object (debug it first), if there is something in it, call the function again with a parameter from the paging object - and so on. just a simple recursive function :)

Answer (score 0):

Graph API by default fetches only 25 photos per album. In order to fetch more you need to set limit on your query as below example. I just had the same issue and solved it as below.

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $album_id . '/photos?fields=images,created_time,updated_time&**limit=200**';
```